# Cron работал только если пользователь авторизован

Tags: ubuntu, unix, cron

На стационарном компе стоит ubuntu 14.04. Настроил задачу в cron для пользователя. Перезагружаю компьютер и не логинюсь в учетку, но крон уже начинает работать. Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы крон не запускался если пользователь не вошел в систему? 
Или надо в скриптах проверять авторизован ли пользователь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

программа `/usr/sbin/cron` обычно запускается как демон при старте операционной системы, и наличие/отсутствие каких-либо процессов, запущенных от имени какого-либо пользователя, (по умолчанию) никакого влияния на процесс запуска этой программы не оказывает.

проверять наличие/отсутствие нужных вам процессов, запущенных нужным вам пользователем, придётся самостоятельно.

p.s. из чтения текста вопроса возникает подозрение, что вы [пытаетесь решить какую-то неозвученную в вопросе задачу явно не тем путём](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/178576).

Comment: Мне надо чтобы крон, который добавлен от имени пользователя работал только если пользователь залогинен. Спасибо за Ваш ответ, я понял, что cron никак не связан с авторизацией данного юзера и решать придётся самостоятельно.